# Tabbed Forms Using HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, tabbed

I've been playing around with some ideas I've been searching for, and I came across this:
http://jsfiddle.net/RcrCJ/

original html

```
        <div id="container">
          <div id="content">
          <ul id="info-nav">
                    <li><a href="#equipment_details"><span>Tab1</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#job_costs"><span>Tab2</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
            <div id="info">
            <form action="inex.html" method="post" id="form1" name="form1" class="formfields">
                <div id="equipment_details" class="hide">

                    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" id="tbl_equipment_details" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="23%" class="txt-right">XXXX</td>
                        <td width="31%"><input type="text" name="" id="qw" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right">XXX</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="" value="1" name="" checked=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right">XXX XXX</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="" name="" id="we" /></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!--tbl_equipment_details closed-->
            </div><!--div equipment_details closed-->

                <!--<div id="specifications" class="hide">-->
                <div id="job_costs" class="hide">
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" width="100%" id="tbl_specifications">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="18%" class="txt-right">Notes</td>
                        <td colspan="2" valign="top">
                            <textarea rows="3" id="description"  cols="60" name=""></textarea>                            </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right">XXX</td>
                        <td width="39%">
                            <select name="purchased_from">
                                <option selected></option>
                                <option value="xxx">xxx1</option>
                                <option value="xxx">xxx2</option>
                                </select>                            </td>
                        <td class="txt-right">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
              <!--</div>

                <div id="job_costs" class="hide">-->                        
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div>
                                <input value="Cancel" name="qq" type="button"> &nbsp;
                                <input value="Save Changes" name="ww" type="submit">
                            </div>                            </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </div><!--div feedback closed-->
              </form>
            </div><!--div info closed-->
        </div><!--div content closed-->
    </div><!--div container closed-->
```

original javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $( '#info #job_costs' ).hide();

  $('#info-nav li').click(function(e) {
    $('#info .hide').hide();
    $('#info-nav .current').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var clicked = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
    $('#info ' + clicked).fadeIn('fast');
    e.preventDefault();
  }).eq(0).addClass('current');
});
```

It was almost exactly what I was looking to do, but I wanted more tabs. I started playing around with it, but for some reason that I can't seem to understand, when I add a third or fourth etc. tab and I run it, it will display all of the tabs until you click on one of them, then it appears normal. I figured it was something silly, but I must have played around with this for hours now and I'm still no further ahead than when I started.

I'm no pro, but I'm usually pretty good at trial / error. This is what I hacked together in an attempt to make 3 tabs:
http://jsfiddle.net/cwaddilove/0Lo7jnoj/

modified html

```
<div id="container">
      <div id="content">
      <ul id="info-nav">
                <li><a href="#equipment_details"><span>Tab1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#job_costs"><span>Tab2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#job_assignment"><span>Tab3</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="info">
            <form action="inex.html" method="post" id="form1" name="form1" class="formfields">
                <div id="equipment_details" class="hide">

                    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" id="tbl_equipment_details" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="23%" class="txt-right">XXXX</td>
                        <td width="31%"><input type="text" name="" id="qw" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right">XXX</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="" value="1" name="" checked=""></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right">XXX XXX</td>
                        <td><input type="text" value="" name="" id="we" /></td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!--tbl_equipment_details closed-->
            </div><!--div equipment_details closed-->

                <!--<div id="specifications" class="hide">-->
                <div id="job_costs" class="hide">
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" width="100%" id="tbl_specifications">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="18%" class="txt-right">Notes</td>
                        <td colspan="2" valign="top">
                            <textarea rows="3" id="description"  cols="60" name=""></textarea>                            </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right">XXX</td>
                        <td width="39%">
                            <select name="purchased_from">
                                <option selected></option>
                                <option value="xxx">xxx1</option>
                                <option value="xxx">xxx2</option>
                                </select>                            </td>
                        <td class="txt-right">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
              <!--</div>

                <div id="job_costs" class="hide">-->                        
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </div><!--div feedback closed-->
                <div id="job_assignment" class="hide">
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" width="100%" id="tbl_assignment">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="18%" class="txt-right">Notes</td>
                        <td colspan="2" valign="top">
                            <textarea rows="3" id="assignment"  cols="60" name=""></textarea>                            </td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="txt-right">XXX</td>
                        <td width="39%">
                            <select name="sold_to">
                                <option selected></option>
                                <option value="xxx">xxx1</option>
                                <option value="xxx">xxx2</option>
                                </select>                            </td>
                        <td class="txt-right">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
              <!--</div>

                <div id="job_costs" class="hide">-->                        
                    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div>
                                <input value="Cancel" name="qq" type="button"> &nbsp;
                                <input value="Save Changes" name="ww" type="submit">
                            </div>                            </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </div><!--div feedback closed-->
              </form>
            </div><!--div info closed-->
        </div><!--div content closed-->
    </div><!--div container closed-->
```

modified javascript

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $( '#info #job_costs #job_assignment' ).hide();

  $('#info-nav li').click(function(e) {
    $('#info .hide').hide();
    $('#info-nav .current').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var clicked = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
    $('#info ' + clicked).fadeIn('fast');
    e.preventDefault();
  }).eq(0).addClass('current');
});
```

I'm hoping someone will be able to see what I've done wrong and can help point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: don't u need to hide all of the infos instead of just one

Comment: Any objection to jQuery tabs?

Comment: Hey Tim - I forgot to mention I was already using jQuery in the jsfiddle example, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in jQuery selector:

```
$( '#info #job_costs #job_assignment' ).hide();
```

To hide several elements you need to put comma in between selectors like this:

```
$( '#info, #job_costs, #job_assignment' ).hide();
```

Solution in your case: you just need to hide two of the tabs so that one would be visible at the beginning. This is what you need to use in your code:

```
$( '#job_costs, #job_assignment' ).hide();
```

There is some room for improvement here but this will work. Here is [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0Lo7jnoj/2/)

Comment: That's phenomenal! I knew it was something silly like that, but I have even less experience with javascript than I do HTML & CSS :) I appreciate the assistance! - I also know there's room for improvement, do you have any suggestions for pointing someone new in the right direction?

Comment: You could replace that line with `$( '.hide:not(:first)' ).hide();`, this will hide all tabs except first one. This way it will not matter how much tabs you have and you would not have to worry about updating ID's every time you change tabs.

Comment: Awesome! Could that in theory also be used if I wanted to duplicate that form in another area? I.E. have two sets of tabs side by side but separate?

I had previously tried putting all the variables for two sets of tabs side by side like that into the script, but it only showed one result div at a time.

Comment: @cwaddilove `$( '.hide:not(:first)' ).hide();` yes, but everything else needs to be changed. You are using some ID's like #info and #info-nav to access elements, this would need to be changed to classes, etc. You should probably open another question for this.

Comment: @cwaddilove I changed some things around so it can be used multiple times on a page: http://jsfiddle.net/0Lo7jnoj/3/ . Note it's just a quick solution, you should probably work on it more.